# karma console showing error even though all test have passed

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular, and have started writing some test cases.

So far my tests are executing but karma console is throwing an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
And I am not sure why its happening even though all tests are successfully passing.

Any suggestions?

data.service.spec.ts

```
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AppDataService } from './app-data.service';

import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

let getExtraReportDataMockData = 'test';
describe('AppDataService', () => {
  let service: AppDataService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let testAppId = 'ap234567';
  let ExtraReportsMockData =  require('./test/ExtraReportsMockData.json');
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports:[
            HttpClientTestingModule
        ],
        providers:[
          AppDataService
        ],
        schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    });
    service  = TestBed.inject(AppDataService);
    httpMock = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should return data fetched by getExtraReportData()', () => {
    console.log('MockData',ExtraReportsMockData);
    service.getExtraReportData(testAppId).subscribe((res) => {
      // expect(Object.keys(res.extraReportData)).toBeTruthy();
      // res.cloudDeploymentData = [];
      console.log(ExtraReportsMockData[0].extraReportData);
      expect(res.extraReportData).toEqual(ExtraReportsMockData[0].extraReportData);
    });
  
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`/api/extra-report-data/${testAppId}`);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
    req.flush(ExtraReportsMockData);
  });
});
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, share, catchError, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClientService } from './http.service';
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppDataService {
  mockData = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClientService) {}

  setMockData(value: boolean): void {
    this.mockData = value;
  }

  getExtraReportData(
    appId: string
  ): Observable<{
    extraReportData: AppInfo;
    cloudDeploymentData: any;
    installData: any;
    additionalAppData: AdditionalAppInfo;
  }> {
    const data: Observable<any> = this.http.get({ url: `/api/extra-report-data/${appId}` });
    return data.pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        if (response.extraReportData.length) {
          const extraData = response.extraReportData[0];

          return {
            ...response,
            extraReportData: {
              ...extraData,
              rbf_governed: extraData.rbf_governed,
              isSOC1: extraData.soc1.toLowerCase() === 'yes',
              development_manager1: extraData.development_manager.split('(')[0],
              application_id_href: `https://abc/text_search_exact_match.do?sysparm_search=${extraData.application_id}`,
              domain_name_href: `http://abc/${extraData.domain_name}`,
              tribe_name_href: `http://abc${extraData.tribe_url}`,
              alternate_squad_name_href: `http://abc${extraData.squad_url}`,
              maturity_level: extraData.maturity_level.slice(1)
            },
            cloudDeploymentData: response.cloudDeploymentData.length ? response.cloudDeploymentData[0] : null
          };
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }

}
```

ExtraReportsMockData.Json

```
{
  "extraReportData": [
    {
      "app_id": "1234567",
      "name": "testing1234Text",
      "product_line_id": "7485296",
      "eligibility": 100,
      "eligibility2": 83,
      "wip_count": 1,
      "wip2_count": 1,
      "wip": "No",
      "acm_wip": "Yes",
      "rbf_combined": "Medium",
      "extra": "Yes",
      "regulated_entities": "No",
    }
  ],
  "cloudDeploymentData": [],
  "installData": [
    {
      "test1": "test1",
      "test2": "test2",
      "test3": "test3",
    },
  ],
  "lifecycleStage": "MyDev"
}
```

Comment: Can you make sure that `response.extraReportData.length` , `extraReportData` is not undefined and `response.cloudDeploymentData.length`, `cloudDeploymentData` is not undefined? I see the mock data and it looks accurate but try putting `console.log(response)` inside of the map to debug and ensure those properties are defined and therefore `.length` will work on them.

Comment: Yes, They are not undefined.